# Equivilent to where() on a Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How would you go about having a where condition in an association? Since it's returning a CollectionProxy which there's barely any information, even in the DOCS, about it. I can't figure out what to do, why wouldn't something like this work?

```
@new_notifications = self.notifications.where({:seen => false})
```

**Figured it out!**
For some reason, passing a hash into the where statement was the problem.
This works:

```
@notifs = self.notifications.where(seen = false)
```

Comment: Every single instance of Notification is default set to false, there's no syntax error for the statement above either. It simply just doesn't get any records, it returns an empty Relation. Anything weird about this SQL? `SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."bit_id" = ? AND "notifications"."seen" = 'f'  [["bit_
id", 4]]`

Comment: Does `Notification.where(:seen => false)` return what you'd expect? Sounds like a problem more with testing boolean values than any collection proxy issue.

Comment: `where(seen = false)` wouldn't work. It would just returns you all notifications. Have you edited your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[`CollectProxy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) is a subclass of `Relation` which means that you can do exactly what you expect.

So, something like:

```
self.notifications.where(:seen => false)
```

Would work provided that you have a `has_many :notifications` association on whatever `self` is.